# Unable to download dateutil, Environment Error

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Trying to download dateutil to run a python script.

I've tried installing it via pip and pip3, but it appears to be calling the wrong python environment.

Used: `pip install python-dateutil==1.4` and got the following:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ff/f4w7vg7x3q9fm911gypt4h8r0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SLYbJ2/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ff/f4w7vg7x3q9fm911gypt4h8r0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SLYbJ2/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/var/folders/ff/f4w7vg7x3q9fm911gypt4h8r0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-SLYbJ2/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ff/
```

then ran `pip3 install python-dateutil==1.4` and got no such module or directory

then ran `pip install -U pip`

Still unsuccessful

Comment: Linux based, correctly? Did you try to run the command with sudo?

Comment: Is there a reasno why you want 1.4, rather than the newest one?

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, run `pip --version` to validate the pip version and the path of your pip. Then, run `where python` to determine the path of your python.

You should see that the paths are similar to confirm that the python environments are correct. Then run pip install

However, I think this is a permission issue. You may want to run the command as an admin (e.g.  `sudo pip install`).

If you don't have access to admin, try the following commands which install on your user account only:

```
pip3 install --user package-name
pip install --user package-name
```

Comment: I think it is a permission and a version issue. When I ran pip3 it said that there was no such file or directory but I have 19.1.1 installed which should be the latest version? When I ran the pip command it said 'requirement already satisfied' but was telling me that it was recognizing python 2.7. see below:

Comment: `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: package-name in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.1)`

Comment: You may want to use pip3 --version and where python3 instead. It depends on your environment variables whether you can default python3 to pip. Do you have python 3 installed? Maybe the best is to find out where python3 is, then check your environment variables to see whether they match the paths that python3 --version provides. If pip3 isn't found, you'll want to look in the same parent directory as python3 is found.